# ical event from php starting at 08:00 regardless of argument

Tags: php, icalendar

I am using php to send an ICS calendar invite using this great function:

```
    function sendIcalEmail($firstname,$lastname,$email,$meeting_date,$meeting_name,$meeting_duration,$address,$details) {

        $from_name = "Jason";
        $from_address = "abc@email.com";
        $subject = "Showing"; //Doubles as email subject and meeting subject in calendar
        $meeting_description = $details;
        $meeting_location = $address; //Where will your meeting take place
      $message='';

        //Convert MYSQL datetime and construct iCal start, end and issue dates
        $meetingstamp = STRTOTIME($meeting_date . " UTC");
        $dtstart= GMDATE("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp);
        $dtend= GMDATE("Ymd\THis\Z",$meetingstamp+$meeting_duration);
        $todaystamp = GMDATE("Ymd\THis\Z");

      echo 'start:'.$dtstart.'<br><br>';
      echo 'end:'.$dtend.'<br><br>';

        //Create unique identifier
        $cal_uid = DATE('Ymd').'T'.DATE('His')."-".RAND()."@mydomain.com";

        //Create Mime Boundry
        $mime_boundary = "----Meeting Booking----".MD5(TIME());

        //Create Email Headers
        $headers = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$from_name." <".$from_address.">\n";

        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$mime_boundary\"\n";
        $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";

        //Create Email Body (HTML)
        $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";
        $message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";

        $message .= "<html>\n";
        $message .= "<body>\n";
        //$message .= '<p>Dear '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.',</p>';
        //$message .= '<p>Here is my HTML Email / Used for Meeting Description</p>';
        $message .= "</body>\n";
        $message .= "</html>\n";
        $message .= "--$mime_boundary\n";

        //Create ICAL Content (Google rfc 2445 for details and examples of usage)
        $ical =    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
    VERSION:2.0
    METHOD:PUBLISH
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    ORGANIZER:MAILTO:'.$from_address.'
    DTSTART:'.$dtstart.'
    DTEND:'.$dtend.'
    LOCATION:'.$meeting_location.'
    TRANSP:OPAQUE
    SEQUENCE:0
    UID:'.$cal_uid.'
    DTSTAMP:'.$todaystamp.'
    DESCRIPTION:'.$meeting_description.'
    SUMMARY:'.$subject.'
    PRIORITY:5
    CLASS:PUBLIC
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR';

        $message .= 'Content-Type: text/calendar;name="meeting.ics";method=REQUEST\n';
        $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n\n";
        $message .= $ical;

        //SEND MAIL
        $mail_sent = @MAIL( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );

        IF($mail_sent)     {
            RETURN TRUE;
        } ELSE {
            RETURN FALSE;
        }

    }
```

On my phone I see the following as the date/time:

Thursday Oct 9, 2014

from 08:00 to 09:00

from 12:00 to 13:00 (GMT)

where my to and from arguments are the following:

```
   start:20141009T120000Z

   end:20141009T130000Z
```

So to me the 08:00 and 09:00 are unexpected. But maybe I am missing something.

Comment: What is your timezone? Your program, probably, shows the original time in UTC/GMT and adds time in your timezone. 12-13 UTC is the same as 8-9 am ET with daylight

Comment: please put as answer. because that is the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your timezone? Your program, probably, shows the original time in UTC/GMT (letter Z - Zulu in timestamp) and adds time in your timezone. 12:00 - 13:00 UTC is the same as 8:00 - 9:00 am ET with daylight. Setup the correct timezone in your start and end times.